# How to: Array of references to value-type fields

Tags: c#

This is a highly contrived example. Don't focus on the seemingly bad design, trivial implementation or holes in the logic.

Let's say I have a class like this...

```
class MyClass : SomeToolkitClass
{
    public bool Enabled00;
    public bool Enabled01;
    public bool Enabled02;

    public int Value00;
    public int Value01;
    public int Value02;

    public String Desc00;
    public String Desc01;
    public String Desc02;

    public void SendDetails( )
    {
        SendDetails( Enabled00, Value00, Desc00 );
        SendDetails( Enabled01, Value01, Desc01 );
        SendDetails( Enabled02, Value02, Desc02 );
    }

    public void SendDetails( bool enabled, int value, string desc )
    {
        if( enabled )
        {
            // do some magic stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

This code "shape" is based on using a third-party toolkit where public facing values must be simple fields. The real logic is much more complex, but follows a similar pattern. I have 32 of each field (not 3) and approximately 7 variable groups (not 3).

What I'd really like is to do something like this (I'm using some imaginary syntax and a little short-hand to demonstrate)

```
List<ref bool> Enabled = { ref Enabled00, ref Enabled01, ref Enabled02 };
List<ref int> Values = { ref Value00, ref Value01, ref Value02 };
List<ref String> Descs = { ref Desc00, ref Desc01, ref Desc02 };

public SendDetails()
{
    for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
        SendDetails( Enabled[i], Values[i], Descs[i] );
}
```

I didn't show it in the example, but there are cases where I want to write to the fields also. (A list of references would probably solve that -- not sure about strings.) Something like this...

```
// ...
if( Enabled[i] && Values[i] == value )
    OtherField[i] = newValue;
// ...
```

Any suggestions? I'm open to alternatives that don't require code like the original SendDetails() method.

Remember...

Don't focus on my specific (trivial) example, focus on the problem.

Having the individual fields is a requirement of the 3rd party toolkit -- I can't change that.

The whole idea around the List of refs comes from knowing that the raw data values can be changed outside of my control. This means buffering the current data values probably isn't practical.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "buffering the current data values". By having local variables, you are already "buffering" them! I would wrap all those values into an object, and hold a list of the objects. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Not possible because you are passing primitive value types. Even if the `List<ref T>` existed, once you pass an element into a method that is not using `ref` for the parameter, it's game over.

Comment: Can't you use ValueType?